# Is it possible to use the Scores & Achievements API from Facebook solely from a native mobile application?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-opengraph

I'm toying around with the Facebook APIs for a game I'm developing as a hobby project, after reading through the facebook SDK documentation, I'm still a little unclear as to what is required for developing games on the platform.

This is what I have :

1. Native iOS application
2. All game data is stored locally (levels, characters, items)
3. I don't have any backend servers, the game is completely client side
   only.

I want to make the game "social" by adding achievements/friends lists, the facebook API seems like a good candidate for doing so

This is what I'm trying to achieve :

- **SSO** - Hoping to make use of the facebook SSO for accounts so I don't
  have to implement my own authentication etc. This saves time in not having to develop it myself.
- **Scores** - when a particular event happens in my game it will award
  some points to the user, I'm looking to use the [scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) for
  this.
- **Achievements** - after the user has earned a certain amount of points,
  or another predefined event has occurred, an achievement will be
  granted, using the [achievements API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/).

**Question : Can I use the scores and achievements APIs from facebook without having my game deployed onto a backend server?**

Comment: I have exactly the same doubt, do you got any insight? 
As I am reading it looks like I have to create a Facebook web app and store there all the meta data info and also use it as a landing page. But I am not sure about that. 
Please let me know any insight about how do you managed to do it. Thx

Comment: If this is an iOS app, have you considered Game Center?

Comment: @JoshHinman In my case its an iOS and Android app, Game Center is just another service and is not as powerful as Facebook. I am not looking for a turn around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, two reasons:

1. You need a URL to host the metadata for your achievements
2. <strike>The scores and achievements need to be posted using the App Access Token, and distributing that in your client app would allow anyone decompiling the app to change any of your app's settings, make posts on behalf of any of the app's users, redirect your traffic to another site, etc.</strike>

At the least, you need static pages describing the achievements, and a callback script you can hit from your mobile app which triggers the publishing to Facebook of the Scores and Achievements

**Update 2012-09-06**: it's [no longer necessary](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) to use the app access token to post scores and achievements, so you could use scores in a mobile app, but you still need a website to hold the achievement metadata

Comment: Ok, I understand the first one but does it implies that in the section "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" of my app control panel I have to select another option in addition to the two that I already have (Native iOS&Android App)? Which one? because I just want to store the metadata. Still a bit confused, sorry.thx

Comment: I believe just the iphone/android integration needs to be selected in the 'how your app integrates with facebook' section, but the domain you host the achievements on needs to be in the 'app domain' field in the section above that

Comment: Is the situation still the same? I'm also struggling with this. Is there a way to use achievements in an Android game, without hosting metadata? Seems like wayyyy too much work for such a simple feature...

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer for this recently.
There's no point in duplicating, so please see the answer here:
[Using Facebook Achievement API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837139/using-facebook-achievement-api-in-android/26954969#26954969)

(It is relevant for iOS as well as any other platform)