# Is app domain required for publishing Facebook Achievements in Graph API v2.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried hosting achievements on our web server and then posting the achivement to the user's timeline with the publish_actions permission from a native iOS & Android app.

In v1 apps, it was required to add the web server where we host the achievements to the app domain settings of the facebook app.
With the new v2 facebook app though, the posting of achievements DID WORK, although I did NOT enter the app domain of the achievement server.

Did this change with Graph API v2.0, and is it supposed to stay like that? (When do we need to set an app domain then?)

This question is also related and describes that it was required to enter the app domains in v1: [Is it possible to use the Scores & Achievements API from Facebook solely from a native mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986772/is-it-possible-to-use-the-scores-achievements-api-from-facebook-solely-from-a)

Comment: _“In v1 apps, it was required to add the web server where we host the achievements to the app domain settings of the facebook app”_ – no it was not; not in general anyway, but _only_ if you set your app up that way regarding security settings (it’s called “Stream post URL security”).

Comment: And that “related” question you mentioned isn’t that much related … it is mainly about whether you need to host your OG objects on the web or not (therefor needing a “backend server”, as the person there puts it) – you don’t, btw. – but not about adding domains to the app settings.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, the "Stream post URL security" makes total sense here and answers the question!


Regarding the 2nd topic: you need some kind of backend server to store the achievement's metadata like the og:image and og:url of the achievement, right?

Comment: “Self-hosted” objects are pages on your server, that deliver the OG meta data – they are identified via their URL. But there is also the [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#objectapi), which lets you create objects that are “hosted” by Facebook themselves – those are simply identified by an ID that gets assigned during their creation.

Comment: Thanks again CBroe!  The Object API looks useful, but for Achievements I don't think it can be used, or to be more specific, for hosting the achievement images it cannot be used, because creating images with the Object API is only possible for user-owned images not for app images. From the doc:
"The staging service is only available for use with user-owned objects and actions. It can't be used with app-owned objects."
So to finish this question, do you agree it is required to host the achievement images on an own backend server? (The achievement objects can then be created with the Object API)